# How can I find the file name in Dev Tools

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When using Chrome Dev Tools, if I inspect an element and see the HTML in the Element tab, how can I find the file name for that HTML? I've tried searching in sources and can't seem to find the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filename of the HTML you see in the Elements panel will always be the same as the URL that you've opened DevTools on.

Sources panel is usually organized by frame context, then domain, then directories.

So, this Stack Overflow post would probably be located here somewhere like:

```
top
|- stackoverflow.com
  |- questions
    |- 42280535
      |- how-can-i-find-the-file-name-in-dev-tools
```